# How to disable one RadioButton out of three in RadioGroup On my form

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

On my form is have one `TRadioGroup`. In that `TRadioGroup`, I add 3 Items. Now I want to disable one item out of three in `TRadioGroup`.

How do I do this? I write code...

```
TRadioButton(rgbLoadSurveyTypes.Controls[1]).Enabled := True;
```

...but it gives error "Access Violation". Reason behind this error is

`rgbLoadSurveyTypes.Controls[1]` give `null` value and
`rgbLoadSurveyTypes` show `ControlCount = 0` and
`Item Count = 3`

Comment: I user Delphi xe10

Comment: At what time are you executing this code? If OnFormCreate the buttons may not exist yet. In which case execute the code in, for example, the OnResize or OnShow event of the form to be sure controls exist.

Comment: Do you see the three RadioButtons in design view of your form?

Comment: What is the `Access violation` message exactly telling you (you can press Ctrl-C to copy its content).

Comment: For future reference, the `Controls` (and `ControlCount`) are direct access to all child controls within a parent control. This applies for any `TWinControl` descendant. However, controls such as `TRadioGroup` are themselves just one control, without sub-controls. Each item is dynamically rendered together. `Controls` is rather, for example, when you have a control on a `TPanel`, or something else which can contain children.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use Buttons property to access individual TRadioButton object.

```
RadioGroup1.Buttons[0].Enabled:= false;
```

[Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCustomRadioGroup.Buttons](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCustomRadioGroup.Buttons)

Comment: rgbLoadSurveyTypes .Buttons[0].Enabled:= false;  this code give error "List Index Out of bounds"

Comment: i migrate code from Delphi 2006 to Xe10.1 ,is there any need to change in RadioGroup property

Comment: Check if you have 3 items in your TRadioGroup, and try to create a new TRadioGroup in XE10.1 without migrate code from Delphi 2006. It works for me in XE10.1 so the problem may be from the migration...

Comment: i use rgbLoadSurveyTypes: TRadioGroup;  and i not get any error when i write code like rgbLoadSurveyTypes.ItemIndex:=1; or rgbLoadSurveyTypes.Visible:= False this code work properly

Comment: when i bebug delphi xe10 and put cursor on rgbLoadSurveyTypes it show TComponent,TControl and TWinControl and when i debug delphi2006 and put cursor on rgbLoadSurveyTypes it show TComponent,TControl and TWinControl,TCustomControl,TCustomRadioGroup here difference is in delphi xe10 rgbLoadSurveyTypes  not show TCustomControl, TCustomRadioGroup , i want to know is above error come because this two not in xe10

Comment: This is not the problem. The problem is, as Dsm mentionned in comment, that maybe you are executing your code in OnFormCreate event, so the buttons don't exist yet. Try to put your code after this event, in the OnShow event.

Comment: Please stop mythering us with the problems that you have in code we can't see. Question you asked has been answered.

Comment: Consider that the order of initialization may have changed slightly in the 10+ years between D2006 and Berlin. Why do you keep saying, "But it did this in D2006"? so what? You're asking how to get it to work in the latest version. I've often found UI elements that aren't initialized as expected within the Form's OnCreate method. So I move the code into OnShow or OnActivate. If you only need it done once, then set a flag.

Comment: The above don't work in C++ Builder 10.3. I get List Index out of bounds error